# Can I make checkbox required?

Tags: docusignapi

According to answer  https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k9V3SAI/how-to-make-a-checkbox-mandatory  checkboxes are always optional fields when signing. But this answer was 2 years ago.Is it possible to make a checkbox required now?

Comment: Whats the point in making a checkbox mandatory? How will you be able to detect if user does not checks because he didn't wanted to and not because he forgot to "not want to check". Better use radio buttons instead.

Comment: A typical use case is I have read the terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox can be either checked or unchecked.
You can decide what is the default. Change it to checked.
If you mean you want the checkbox to be always cheked - it has to be readonly and marked checked by your code.